# upgrade Azure OpenLogic Centos 6.7 to CentOS 7.2

Tags: azure, centos, azure-virtual-machine

What is the best way to upgrade Azure Openlogic CentOS 6.7 to CentOS7.2 So that it has it is similar to CentOS 7.2 image.
I did sudo yum update but it did not upgrade to the latest version. Can some provide the steps for upgrading to the latest major version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest deploying a new OS with CentOS 7.2 template and then migrate the data and configuration from the older VM.

In-place upgrading is error-prone. For now, the official website of the CentOS also doesn't suggest the in-place upgrade from 6 to 7.

[DO NOT USE this tool. Warning: use of this tool is currently BROKEN as several system-critical packages are of a higher version number in CentOS 6.7 than they are in CentOS 7 so those do not get upgraded correctly. This renders yum and several other system tools non-functional.](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CentOSUpgradeTool)